# Order By Multi Select Choice List on SharePoint Views

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list-view, multi-select

I have a view in which it is a multi select choice list.  When creating a view, I cannot select to order by customer with a multi select.  This does work for me if I have a single Select Choice List.  Is there any work around?  Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Order By - Note that Customer is not displayed]

Answer (score 1):

Choice columns with multiple selections cannot be used for grouping by, sorting or ordering under any circumstance.

You will have to use another column that is not a multi-value column for those actions, for example, use a calculated column to identify what values are filled using numbers or plain texts, then grouping by the calculated column.

These can barely be called “workarounds” from my perspective, but at least they work for grouping by.

Comment: This doesn't work. Multiple choice columns can't be used in formulas. Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c4535103-d019-4e74-8529-39d8acf63a40/how-to-create-calculated-column-which-shows-yesno-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we cannot sort the multichoice columns. Some workarounds:

**Workaround**

For each choice, create a new "Yes/No" column. For example, if you have `Red`, `Green`, `Blue` choices, then create new three columns:

- Name: `Red`, Type: `Yes/No`
- Name: `Green`, Type: `Yes/No`
- Name: `Blue`, Type: `Yes/No`

Then you can sort and filter by individual columns you have create.